# How to properly exclude group in regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need to match in some text some pattern, but this pattern should not have another pattern.
I use in html some groups and html page does not add new line. Rather than new line in html added 
 so I get trouble here.

I try to use this regex:

```
/\|([^\r\n|]+?(?!<br>))\|/igm
```

and example is:

```
test1 | test2 | test3<br>| test4<br>| test5 |<br>test6
```

Should be matching only `| test2 |` and group `test2`, but right now also matching `| test4<br>|` and not right `| test5 |`. I need to exclude test4 match, but don't know how to use it with `[]` because it ignored `(?!<br>)`.

P.S. of course `| test2 |` also may be `| text1 <span ...>text2</span> text3 |`, so placing `<>` into `[]` is not a solution I need.

Comment: Please show an example string (concrete examples) instead of incomprehensible descriptions

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, this is a good example.

1) I get object what I need to edit.

2) Get innterHTML of it and apply `.replace()` function with that regex.

The problem is in some situation it should not be selected. As I say HTML contain `<br>`, rather than `\r\n` and I can't except just newline character, because <br> is a group of 4 characters, not one.

Comment: @XCanG: you mean `\|(?:(?!<br\s*\/?>)[^\r\n|])*\|`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fU2xF9/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, oh, thanks, the following regex I need is `\|((?:(?!<br\s*\/?>)[\s\S])*?)\|` But how now mark question answered?

Comment: Let me put it as an answer.

Comment: And yeah, forget replace [\s\S] to [^\r\n|].
`\|((?:(?!<br\s*\/?>)[^\r\n|])*?)\|` is answer.

Comment: You do not need the lazy quantifier, it can be greedy because the `|` is not matched by the tempered greedy token (since it appears inside the negated character class). Also, a lazy quantifier will slow down matching here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you need should be based on a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
/\|((?:(?!<br\s*\/?>)[^\r\n|])*)\|/gi
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP6lP8/2)

The token is `(?:(?!<br\s*\/?>)[^\r\n|])*` and it matches any character other than a CR/LF/`|` (the `[^\r\n|]` negated character class accounts for that) that is not starting a `<br>` tag sequence (or `<br >` or `<br/>` or `<br />`, etc.)
The contents matched with the token are captured into group #1 since it is wrapped with a capturing parentheses `(...)`.

JS demo:

```js
var re = /\|((?:(?!<br\s*\/?>)[^\r\n|])*)\|/ig; 
var str = 'test1 | test2 | test3<br>| test4<br>| test5 |<br>test6|';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]); // Grab Group 1 value only
}
console.log(res);
```